# How to get values from 3 models and build a structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three models. Location, Product and Stock.

I am trying to build a report around Stock for each location for each product.

So i am aiming for something like this

Location A
Product A Quantity A
Product B Quantity B

and do that for all locations

what the best way going about it?

models

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stocks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :locations, :through => :stocks
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stocks
  has_many :products, :through => :stocks
end

class Stock < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location, optional: true
  belongs_to :product, optional: true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord allows you to access associated objects through dot notation. In your view, you can loop through each of your locations and display the associated products and stocks.

```
@locations.each do |l|
    l.products.each do |p|
        puts p.name
    end
    l.stocks.each do |s|
        puts s.name
    end
end
```

Put this in a table or list format to your liking.